# triggering another jenkins job from jenkinsfile in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to invoke a separate jenkins job whose direct job url is `https://jenkins.example.com/job/jobName/`. This job runs with one parameter name "branch", whose value is "Master".

Below is how I am giving in my `Jenkinsfile`, but when I run it, gives me error

> ERROR: No item named https://jenkins.example.com/job/jobName found

```java
if ("${params.buildParam}" == 'test' || !params.buildParam ){
  stage('Test') {
    def job = build job: 'https://jenkins.example.com/job/jobName/', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'branch', value: 'Master']]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) step takes a job name as parameter, not a URL. So try

```java
build job: '/jobName'
```

to refer using the absolute path. Depending on where your pipeline job is, you might use something like the following as well:

```java
build job: '../../jobName/'
```

btw. you can avoid string interpolation here:

```java
if (params.buildParam == 'test' ...)
```

Comment: Thanks StephenKing! I got it working thanks to adding the / in front of the job name.